# License of NOAA hourly temperature data

Tags: licensing, weather, noaa

I would like use historic hourly temperature data (Integrated Surface Global Hourly Data, DSI-3505) available from NOAA. Using NOAA's [Climate Data Online mapping tool](http://gis.ncdc.noaa.gov/map/viewer/), I select the weather stations in the region I'm interested in (Belgium, in my case) and download the data between two particular dates in a CSV format. Using this data, I can determine an approximation of the temperature at a particular location (long/lat) at a given point in time.

While this data is freely downloadable, it is not clear to me whether I can use it for commercial purposes. The data is not being sold as-is, I'm merely querying it as part of a research project we're doing for another company. That company will use the resulting data internally, not sell or distribute it in any other way.

Before I can download the data, the following text is presented to me (emphasis mine):

> CONDITIONS
>
> WMO Resolution 40 NOAA Policy
>
> The following data and products **may** have conditions placed on their
>   international commercial use. They can be used within the U.S. or for
>   non-commercial international activities without restriction. The
>   non-U.S. data cannot be redistributed for commercial purposes.
>   Re-distribution of these data by others must provide this same
>   notification. A log of IP addresses accessing these data and products
>   will be maintained and may be made available to data providers.
>
> For details, please consult [WMO Resolution 40](http://www.wmo.int/pages/about/Resolution40.html).
>
> For additional details/information concerning which data are listed as
>   "additional," please see the [Microsoft Word document WMO Resolution 40](http://www.map.meteoswiss.ch/WMO/WMOresol40.htm)
>   If you have questions about NCDC's implementation of this resolution, 
>   please contact NCDC at ncdc.orders@noaa.gov or 828-271-4800.

I started reading the referenced *WMO Resolution 40*, but I'm pretty sure I can't figure out what it's saying in a reasonable amount of time. I was hoping someone else has experience with this and can shed some light on the matter.

Comment: I note email and phone contact points prominently indicated to get answers directly from the source. I suggest contacting them, and then maybe self-answering this question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have contacted NOAA directly with this question, and the answer was (emphasis mine):

> As you have described it below, you are not in violation of Resolution
>   40. This would apply if you are **redistributing the data as-is for profit**.

If you are unsure about your particular use case, I suggest contacting NOAA directly.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for going the extra mile to get this clarified!